# SVG html5 draw characters

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Let's say I have to refactor some code and change it.
I have an svg object that looks like this:

```
<svg>
 <g>
   <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M267.2,605.4l0.5-4l-1.1-0.6l0.2-1l2.7-0.6l0.5,0.3l-0.8,6c-0.2,1.3-0.3,2.2-0.3,3.3      c0,1.5,0.6,1.9,1.6,1.9c1,0,2.1-0.7,2.8-1.4l1.3-10h2.1l-1.4,10.6c-0.1,0.6,0,0.8,0.2,0.8c0.2,0,0.5-0.1,1.2-0.7l0.3,0.6      c-0.2,0.3-1.4,1.6-2.7,1.6c-0.9,0-1.4-0.6-1.2-1.5c-0.8,0.8-2,1.5-3.6,1.5c-1.7,0-2.8-0.7-2.8-3      C266.8,608.2,267,606.7,267.2,605.4z"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

As an out put here I get the letter "U".

So how can write in such manner anything for example I want to write "stackoverflow" using this technology?

Comment: Do you need to draw the letters individually? Could you use the text element `<text x="10" y="10">stackoverflow</text>`

Comment: @GrahamWalters no, I can use text element indeed

Comment: Use a tool such as Inkscape.